# How do I remove empty spaces and lines within a string?

Tags: python, string, strip

This is what I have

```
S = """Missing Since 06/01/1976

Missing From 
                                Napa,                               California                          
Classification Endangered Missing
Sex Female
Race 
                                    White
Date of Birth 02/06/1957 (63)
Age 19 years old
Height and Weight 5'2, 130 pounds
Distinguishing Characteristics Caucasian female. Brown hair, hazel eyes."""
```

Which I want to get to

```
S = """Missing Since 06/01/1976
Missing From Napa,California                            
Classification Endangered Missing
Sex Female
Race White
Date of Birth 02/06/1957 (63)
Age 19 years old
Height and Weight 5'2, 130 pounds
Distinguishing Characteristics Caucasian female. Brown hair, hazel eyes."""
```

I tried using `S.strip()`, but that only removed the spaces at the beginning and the end.

I was wondering if there was any implementation (I couldn't find any) that would work.

I also tried using `S.replace("  ","")` for the bigger spaces but that also got me nowhere.

Comment: Is it in a file?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Comment: What does "based on input" mean? How are you getting the string?

Comment: @Random, I added some more explanation of the topic, Also as future reference.

Answer (score 1):

removes multiple spaces (not lines):

```
print( ' '.join([s for s in S.split(' ') if s.strip()]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import re


def normalize_text(get_text):
    saved_new_lines = []
    counter = 0
    for each_line in get_text.split("\n"):
        if not each_line == "":
            normalize_each_line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', each_line.strip())
            if each_line.startswith(" "):
                saved_new_lines[counter-1] += " " + normalize_each_line
            else:
                saved_new_lines.append(normalize_each_line)
                counter += 1
    return "\n".join(saved_new_lines)


print(normalize_text(S))
```

Output:

```
Missing Since 06/01/1976
Missing From Napa, California
Classification Endangered Missing
Sex Female
Race White
Date of Birth 02/06/1957 (63)
Age 19 years old
Height and Weight 5'2, 130 pounds
Distinguishing Characteristics Caucasian female. Brown hair, hazel eyes.
```

@FedericoBaù gave me the hint; so i updated my code (this version dose not have any empty-line checker so it will be much faster than its current status)

**Updated:**

```
import re


def normalize_text(get_text):
    saved_new_lines = []
    counter = 0
    for each_line in re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', get_text.strip()).splitlines():
        normalize_each_line = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', each_line.strip())
        if each_line.startswith(" "):
            saved_new_lines[counter-1] += " {}".format(normalize_each_line)
        else:
            saved_new_lines.append(normalize_each_line)
            counter += 1
    return "\n".join(saved_new_lines)


print(normalize_text(test_string))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally see it now

Comment: @Random so i appreciate if you accept and upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to produce the requested string literal output using only the string literal input, as (was originally) requested:

```
from re import sub

print(sub('Race\n', 'Race ',
          sub('Missing From\n', 'Missing From ', '\n'.join(
              [sub(' \s', '', line) for line in [line.strip() for line in """
"Missing Since 06/01/1976

Missing From
                                Napa,                               California
Classification Endangered Missing
Sex Female
Race
                                    White
Date of Birth 02/06/1957 (63)
Age 19 years old
Height and Weight 5'2, 130 pounds
Distinguishing Characteristics Caucasian female. Brown hair, hazel eyes."
""".split('\n') if line.strip()]]))))
```

Output:

```
"Missing Since 06/01/1976
Missing From Napa, California
Classification Endangered Missing
Sex Female
Race White
Date of Birth 02/06/1957 (63)
Age 19 years old
Height and Weight 5'2, 130 pounds
Distinguishing Characteristics Caucasian female. Brown hair, hazel eyes."
```

Comment: It's not the way I would implement in my own code, but I tackled it as a puzzle to solve as requested :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck and this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am not into python but as far as i know  in php those spaces appear because of `\n` and `\r`, To fix you can simply do `string.replace("<double-space-here>","")` then get the variable and redo the process but this time replace "\n" then "\r". I would be better if you could find a inbuilt method to filter html characters in python.

Answer (score 0):

@Random despite the already very useful answer, I would like to give some more insight regarding the issue you have faced, which is very usual, especially because of how the function `strip` expectations are.

Logically one may think that it should remove all items within a string, but it does only at the 2 extremity and not 'within' the string, but why?

You should first understand how string a really stored inside Python, they are like 'arrays' (kind of list) really for instance:

```py
string = "  Hello world "
```

In reality is:

```py
string = [" ", " ", "H", 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ']
```

So the strip function go and check whatever character it finds from the left and right of the string and stops until encounters a different character.

**Hence it won't loop at the whole string (array) but only from index 0 or index -1!**

For more regarding this, I suggest to have a look at [array-of-strings-in-c](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-strings-in-c/), despite is not Python, Python is written in C and internally has the same implementation.

### Some Solutions (Not yet given)

1. Use [string.whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace)

   ```py
        import string

        def string_cleaner(str):
            cleaned_string = []
            string_separated = str.split(' ')
            for word in string_separated:
                if word:
                    if word in string.whitespace:
                        del word
                    else:
                        cleaned_string.append(word)

            ready_baby = ' '.join(cleaned_string)
            return ready_baby


        result = string_cleaner(test_string)
   ```

--> Short form using list comprehension

```py
print(' '.join([s for s in test_string.split(' ') if s and s not in string.whitespace]))
```

2. Use Function [isspace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isspace-application/) (NO IMPORT NEDDED, pure built-in)

   ```py
    def string_cleaner(str):
        cleaned_string = []
        string_separated = str.split(' ')
        for word in string_separated:
            if word:
                if word.isspace():
                    del word
                else:
                    cleaned_string.append(word)

        ready_baby = ' '.join(cleaned_string)
        return ready_baby


    result = string_cleaner(test_string)

    print(result)
   ```

--> Short form using list comprehension

```py
print(' '.join([string for string in test_string.split(' ') if string and not string.isspace()]))
```

---

### Re-visit re.sub function

Here is a reproduction of what `re.sub` does, note that I added many "useless" variables in order to make the code more explicit:

```py
def string_cleaner(str):

    cleaned_string = []
    string_separated = str.split(' ')
    for word in string_separated:
        if word: # Not Blank line
            remove_whitespace_from_side = word.strip().replace('\n', ' ') # NOTE: we do this because there are multiple \n\n in some string
            separate_each_string = remove_whitespace_from_side.split()
            if separate_each_string:  # NOTE: If empty means that is a useless white spece within a string
                rejoined_sub_string = ' '.join(separate_each_string)
                ready_string = rejoined_sub_string.replace(' ', '\n') # Add again \n
                cleaned_string.append(ready_string)
    ready_to_go = ' '.join(cleaned_string)
    return ready_to_go

result = string_cleaner(test_string)

print(result)
```

---

### Documentation

- [Python Re Sub function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

> "Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.".

What it does is similar to C function [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm), more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#simulating-scanf).

- [list-comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
- [join method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

Comment: (SO isn't [CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).)

Comment: @greybeard if you assume this because I added other users answers and changed it then isn't a review but a needed clarification of it (as they haven't provide) and not a **review**  especially based on the  nature of issue which is the mistaken expectation of how `strip` function works. I realized now that it look like my intention was to review others code but it wasn't . I edit my answer to avoid this disambiguation

Comment: @FedericoBaù cheers; i saw your comment; tnx for your pythonic version i updated my answer and changed it a little bit.

Comment: @DRPK you welcome, I see some code and i couldn't resist and I'm glad you've taken it in a way that makes you improve it and not as a mere critic, the algorithm it's self is really good! Thumbed up your answer  and happy new year ;)

Comment: @FedericoBaù happy new year bro/sis :); i suggest to do some code comparison with timit module for each function (include my code) and report it on your answer; iam curoius about their speed or memory usage ... your answer well explained enough. this answer should be accepted